# post-checkout git hook not working

Tags: git, githooks, git-checkout

I have git checkout hook called post-checkout

```
$ ll  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.3.5/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-checkout 

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  375 Aug 13 14:11 /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.3.5/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-checkout
```

the content of post-checkout is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Hello from post-checkout"

# Delete .pyc files and empty directories from root of project
cd ./$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)

# Clean-up
find . -name ".DS_Store" -delete

NUM_PYC_FILES=$( find . -name "*.pyc" | wc -l | tr -d ' ' )
if [ $NUM_PYC_FILES -gt 0 ]; then
    find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
    printf "\e[00;31mDeleted $NUM_PYC_FILES .pyc files\e[00m\n"
fi
```

so when I cloned my repo i passed the path of templates to template flag like this:

```
$ git clone  https://sanfx@bitbucket.org/sanfx/git-maildiff.git --template=/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.3.5/share/git-core/templates/
```

but after i clone and CD to that cloned directory of git-maildiff and I try checkout I get nothing .

```
$ git clone  https://sanfx@bitbucket.org/sanfx/git-maildiff.git --template=/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.3.5/share/git-core/templates/
Cloning into 'git-maildiff'...
remote: Counting objects: 239, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (215/215), done.
remote: Total 239 (delta 109), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (239/239), 72.90 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (109/109), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ git checkout
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

but if i ran my executable post-checkout branch I get the Hello from post-checkout printed in shell.

so what is wrong where ?

Comment: Why do you execute empty `git checkout`? Do you want to switch the branch or what? Can you hit `git checkout another_branch`? Does the hook work now?

Comment: @zaratustra I have tried that already, that too didn't worked .

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) post-checkout script receive 3 parameters. I had a similar issue and I resolved adding a line to read those parameters (It doesn't matter that they aren't used). The script will look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read previousref newref flag
echo "Hello from post-checkout"
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update this file:

```
<repo>/.git/hooks/post-checkout
```

instead of this one:

```
<repo>/.githooks/post-checkout
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `post-checkout` file is set as executable. Git will ignore it otherwise.

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-checkout
```